# Liquibase tableExists not scaling

Tags: liquibase

I am running a ChangeSet that needs to check it a table exists in the precondition. So my ChangeSet looks like

```
<changeSet author="James" id="1548255530845-100">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                    <tableExists tableName="MY_NEW_TABLE" schemaName="${my_schema}"></tableExists>
            </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="MY_NEW_TABLE">
        <column name="IDX" type="${integer.type}">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="INTVAL" type="${integer.type}"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

When I run this on a large database/schema it is taking a very long time to run.

Debugging the code the internals of Liquibase is calling SnapshotGeneratorFactory.has(DatabaseObject, Database)

```
public boolean has(DatabaseObject example, Database database) throws DatabaseException, InvalidExampleException {
    List<Class<? extends DatabaseObject>> types = new ArrayList<Class<? extends DatabaseObject>>(getContainerTypes(example.getClass(), database));
    types.add(example.getClass());

    //workaround for common check for databasechangelog/lock table to not snapshot the whole database like we have to in order to handle case issues
    if (example instanceof Table && (example.getName().equals(database.getDatabaseChangeLogTableName()) || example.getName().equals(database.getDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName()))) {
        try {
            ExecutorService.getInstance().getExecutor(database).queryForInt(new RawSqlStatement("select count(*) from " + database.escapeObjectName(database.getLiquibaseCatalogName(), database.getLiquibaseSchemaName(), example.getName(), Table.class)));
            return true;
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            if (database instanceof PostgresDatabase) { //throws "current transaction is aborted" unless we roll back the connection
                database.rollback();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (createSnapshot(example, database, new SnapshotControl(database, false, types.toArray(new Class[types.size()]))) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    CatalogAndSchema catalogAndSchema;
    if (example.getSchema() == null) {
        catalogAndSchema = database.getDefaultSchema();
    } else {
        catalogAndSchema = example.getSchema().toCatalogAndSchema();
    }
    DatabaseSnapshot snapshot = createSnapshot(catalogAndSchema, database, new SnapshotControl(database, false, example.getClass()));
    for (DatabaseObject obj : snapshot.get(example.getClass())) {
        if (DatabaseObjectComparatorFactory.getInstance().isSameObject(example, obj, null, database)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code is then creating a snapshot of the database & looping through every table to check if it "isSameObject"

This just does not scale, the more tables I have in my database the longer it is going to take to check if the table exists.

I notice there is a comment in the method higher up for a "workaround" so looking up the databasechangelog/lock table does not have to perform this kind of snapshot then unscaleable look up.

Is there be a scaleable way to check if a table exists/does not exist in a precondition?

Another minor issue with the method: the List types at the start of the method contains "class liquibase.structure.core.Table" twice when I am checking if a tables exists. Shouldn't this be a Set - so avoiding the duplicate? And shouldn't it be only populated after the "workround" has been performed?

Comment: After further investigation if the table does not exist it is taking of the order of 3 minutes to check it does not exist. But if the table does exists it is taking milliseconds to check it is there. This is because if the table does not exists its performing the loop to check all tables at the bottom of the method. My work round is to write my CustomTableExistsPredcondition.